# Is there a way to refresh an activity once we enter it?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

Because in my Checkout Activity. After I put an information of the user in the database firebase and when I pressed the checkout. That data duplicates a lot that makes the scroll bar small. But when I refresh the activity by using a button it becomes what I want it to be.

I want to refresh by using this.

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
    finish();
    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    startActivity(intent);
```

I used handler but it kept refreshing none stop. And I don't know how to refresh it once. Is there a way to refresh an activity once entering it?

Comment: If you are calling it on oncreate, then keep a variable to maintain checkout status in sharedpreferences or some stroge  then check it before call this refresh code

Answer (score 0):

There are **multiple ways** that you can do that. The simplest way is using `shared preferences`. You can define a `boolean` variable in your `activity` and initialize it in the `onCreate` method using `shared preferences` and check if the value is `true`, then set it to `false` and **restart** the `activity`.
**Note** that you should set it `true` again in the `onDestroy` method for the next time. A simple example is shown below:

```
 private SharedPreferences pref;

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    boolean isFirstTime = pref.getBoolean("isFirstTime", true);
    if (isFirstTime){
        pref.edit().putBoolean("isFirstTime", false).apply();

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
        finish();
        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    //your codes ....
    }



@Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        pref.edit().putBoolean("isFirstTime", true).apply();
    }
```

Of course in some situations, ***onDestroy method maybe not be called***.

A better way is using `DataStore` instead of `shared preferences`. Nowadays **Google advises** using `DataStore`.

Another and my favorite way is using **MVVM architecture** and setting the state in the `ViewModel`. in this way you don't need `shared preferences` or `DataStore`.

***P.S***

If you want to use shared preferences I suggest you set `pref.edit().putBoolean("isFirstTime", true).apply();`
in your splash screen or another place instead of onDestroy method.

Comment: Where should I put the shared preferences? In the onDestroy? or OnCreate?